# Visual Studio Code SFTP to multiple servers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In PhpStorm, there is a way to configure multiple SFTP endpoints and chose which server you want to upload to. I'm looking for this functionality in Visual Studio Code. I have installed [SFTP VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp) and I am able to configure it for one endpoint.  What if I want to upload a file to multiple servers? How can I configure that? Or is there another extension that does that?

Comment: did you try this extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp#multiple-context

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of add-ins that will work for your requirements. Below are a list of few

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-deploy

[image: Deploy]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-deploy-reloaded

[image: Deploy Reloaded]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple

[image: ftp-simple]

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when OP clearly asked for sFTP extension from liximomo (now Natizyskunk)?

The extension can handle multiple profiles easily without adding other extension or changing it

Answer (score 22):

Hi you can add multiple ftp servers to config. Just The **context** must not be same.

```js
[
  {
    "name": "server1",
    "context": "/project/build",
    "host": "host",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remotePath": "/remote/project/build"
  },
  {
    "name": "server2",
    "context": "/project/src",
    "host": "host",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remotePath": "/remote/project/src"
  }
]
```

Comment: To clarify, the 'context' refers to the path to which the files will be downloaded, and to avoid conflicts with folders/files with the same names in the different folders. Aditionally, the example shows them as absoulte paths, from the root folder `/`, I recommend setting them as relative to your default SFTP folder, e.g. `./path/to/server1files`

Comment: Note that you can't use multiple servers with the same context.

Comment: Does this give me the option to upload to one server at a time, or they will sync to both together?

Comment: @DiegoDD you mean "from which the path will be downloaded" or did you mean "from which the path will be uploaded"?

Comment: when I try your solution only one of my servers updates. Why?

Comment: @CharlieParker `context` is your LOCAL path, `remotePath` is just that. It means that `/remote/project/build/someFile.txt` would be downloaded to `/project/build/someFile.txt` locally, to be able to edit it, and when saved, reuploaded to the remote path. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you want full copies sent to both servers, what options do we need to specify?

Comment: While trying to help, this anwser does not really address the original question's target. Answer by @wraithKenny regarding to profiles gets closer to it.

Answer (score 14):

You can use "profiles" with the SFTP extension now. https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp#profiles

```
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "protocol": "sftp",
  "remotePath": "/",
  "port": 22,
  "profiles": {
    "dev": {
      "host": "server1.example.com",
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
    },
    "prod": {
      "host": "server2.example.com",
      "username": "other-username",
      "password": "other-password"
    }
  },
  "defaultProfile": "dev"
}
```

Comment: can you have individual remote paths rather than one at the top of the project?

Comment: also, I want to push to BOTH on save not only 1 one of them, is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can set up remotePath for each of your profiles like that: (I saw that such question was asked by @Charlie Parker in the second answer to that question)

```
{
    "name": "ExampleName",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22,
    "profiles": {
        "profile1": {
            "host": "connection1",
            "username": "user1",
            "remotePath":"/path1"
        },
        "profile2": {
            "host": "connection2",
            "username": "user2",
            "remotePath":"/path2"
        },
        "profile3": {
            "host": "connection3",
            "username": "user3",
            "remotePath":"/path3"
        },
    }
}
```

And with Ctrl+Sifht+P > Set Profile you can change your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> ```
>     [
>     {
>       "name": "project 1",
>       "context": "/project/project1",
>       "host": "",
>       "username": "",
>       "password": "",
>       "protocol": "ftp",
>       "post": 21,
>       "remotePath": "/",
>       "uploadOnSave": true 
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "project 2",
>       "context": "/project/project2",
>       "host": "",
>       "username": "",
>       "password": "",
>       "protocol": "ftp",
>       "post": 21,
>       "remotePath": "/",
>       "uploadOnSave": true 
>     }
>   ]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
[
  {
    "name": "server1",
    "context": "/project/build",
    "host": "host",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remotePath": "/remote/project/build"
  },
  {
    "name": "server2",
    "context": "/project/src",
    "host": "host",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "remotePath": "/remote/project/src"
  }
]
```